# PostGIS availability for Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, postgis

Are there any plans to add PostGIS functionality to Google BigQuery? It would make for an extremely powerful GIS analysis tool and seems like a natural fit (aside the parallelization issues).

Answer (score 5):

More good news: BigQuery GIS doesn't need whitelisting anymore, just get in BigQuery and try it out.

---

Good news:

BigQuery GIS and BigQuery Geo Viz are in public alpha now. To request access to both, please fill out this form. We’ll whitelist your GCP projects and send you the BigQuery GIS documentation.

- Announcement: https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2018/07/bridging-the-gap-between-data-and-insights
- Form: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdaf8RsWhQSvC6hnasaRhrtghmiGyDr2z0Vf97w5IDuwUlXdg/viewform

Comment: this is great. I've filled out the form last week but haven't received an update since.

Answer (score 2):

Google BigQuery Team is working on adding postGIS functionality to Google BigQuery

You can follow up https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38187385

Comment: really cool, is it possible to provide an estimate for a first implementation?

Comment: usually Google Team does not provide ETA, but as I mentioned  - you can follow up using link in answer - and they will give you at least some info :o)

Comment: great, I've added my two cents to the discussion. Looking forward to see this moving forward.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2018/07/bridging-the-gap-between-data-and-insights

Answer (score 2):

BigQuery GIS is in beta now.  Here is the link to the documentation:  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/gis-intro